# Stata: If statement with variable names

Tags: stata

I want to create an `if` statement in Stata based on the variable names. However, I couldn't find a way to create a local for variable names i.e. `variable_name_x'

```
foreach x of varlist dummyind_* { 
hist x if `variable_name_x'==ind
}

clear
input float dummyind_1 float dummyind_2 str10 ind 
0.1 0.7  dummyind_1
0.1 0.5 dummyind_2 
0.2 0.8 dummyind_1 
0.3 0.3 dummyind_2 
0.4 0.2 dummyind_1 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly puzzling data structure, but I think I understand the question and guess you need something more like

```
foreach x of var dummy_ind* { 
    hist `x' if ind == "`x'" 
}
```

That is, each variable name in question has two roles: (1) as a variable name (2) as a value of another string variable.

The above is using an `if` qualifier, not an `if` statement, which is different.